# WSO2 Authentication failure on gateway node running WSO2 AM 2.1.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

After working with WSO2 AM 1.10.0, we're now evaluating AM 2.1.0 for our WSO2 cluster. The cluster has two types of nodes:

- A manager node: a complete set of WSO2 AM products.
- A worker node: which runs only the gateway (-DworkerNode=true -Dprofile=gateway-worker)

At the manager node, everything works ok. I am able to create a tenant (0000s7.com) and an API, and run it (I defined the GET verb to be unauthenticated, so no subscription is needed):

```
    $ curl http://localhost:8280/t/0000s7.com/ofer1/1.0.0
    { ...valid response... }
```

At the worker node:

When I’m working with WSClient, I get the following error in the log:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-06 07:26:48,893] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet} -   
{org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet} java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTUtils.getFullRequestPath(RESTUtils.java:80)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.canProcess(API.java:223)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:97)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:69)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:304)
```

I also tried ThriftClient, with it I get a different error in the log:

```
   TID: [1] [] [2018-02-06 08:01:29,527] @0000s7.com [1] [AM] 
WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.thrift.ThriftKeyValidatorClien    t} -  
Login failed.. Authenticating again..{org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.thrift.ThriftKeyValidatorClient}
```

In both cases, API call ends with

```
<ams:fault xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security">
<ams:code>900900</ams:code><ams:message>Unclassified Authentication Failure</ams:message>
<ams:description>Error while accessing backend services for API key validation</ams:description>
</ams:fault>
```

Quick summary of changes. Currently I left the WSClient version to run:

***Manager Node*** (internal IP 10.1.0.7)

- ./repository/conf/api-manager.xml

  > ```
  >         <KeyValidatorClientType>WSClient</KeyValidatorClientType>
  >         <ThriftClientConnectionTimeOut>10000</ThriftClientConnectionTimeOut>
  >         <ThriftClientPort>10397</ThriftClientPort>
  >
  >         <EnableThriftServer>false</EnableThriftServer>
  >         <ThriftServerHost>10.1.0.7</ThriftServerHost>
  >         <ThriftServerPort>10397</ThriftServerPort>
  > ```
- ./repository/conf/carbon.xml

> ```
>       <HostName>10.1.0.7</HostName>
>       <MgtHostName>10.1.0.7</MgtHostName>
> ```

- ./repository/conf/registry.xml
- ./repository/conf/user-mgt.xml

> Minor changes to adopt to the MySQL DB

- ./repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml

> ```
>             <property name="subDomain" value="mgt"/>
>             <property name="port.mapping.80" value="9763"/>
>             <property name="port.mapping.443" value="9443"/>
> ```

- ./repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml

> ```
> Changed to work with RDS using MySQL. 
> I'm using four databases:
> o regdb_21 (the “shared” registry”
> o apimgtdb_21
> o userdb_21
> o msgbrokerdb_21
> In addition, stats DB and local registry are maintained in H2.
> ```

***Worker Node*** (Internal IP 10.1.0.150)

- ./bin/wso2server.sh

> ```
>      -DworkerNode=true \
>      -Dprofile=gateway-worker \
> ```

- ./repository/conf/api-manager.xml

> ```
>         <KeyValidatorClientType>WSClient</KeyValidatorClientType>
>         <ThriftClientPort>10397</ThriftClientPort>
>         <ThriftClientConnectionTimeOut>10000</ThriftClientConnectionTimeOut>
>
>         <ThriftServerHost>10.1.0.7</ThriftServerHost>
>         <ThriftServerPort>10397</ThriftServerPort>
>         <EnableThriftServer>false</EnableThriftServer>
>         <JMSConnectionDetails>
>             <Enabled>false</Enabled>
>             …
>
>    Plus some changes of JMS IP to the IP address of the manager (10.1.0.7)
> ```

- ./repository/conf/carbon.xml

> ```
>       <HostName>10.1.0.150</HostName>
>       <MgtHostName>10.1.0.150</MgtHostName>
> ```

- ./repository/conf/registry.xml
- ./repository/conf/user-mgt.xml

> ```
>             Minor changes to adopt to the MySQL DB
> ```

- ./repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml

> ```
>          <property name="port.mapping.80" value="9763"/>
>          <property name="port.mapping.443" value="9443"/>
> ```

- ./repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml

> ```
>         Same as in manager
> ```

- ./repository/conf/broker.xml
- ./repository/conf/event-broker.xml
- ./repository/conf/jndi.properties
- ./repository/conf/messaging-event-broker.xml

> ```
>   Changes in IP from localhost to 10.1.0.7
> ```

Complete logs

- Manager: http://thatsitradio.com/logs1/manager.html
- Worker: http://thatsitradio.com/logs1/worker.html

Comment: Can you post the complete error log in worker? do you see any errors in manager side?

Comment: Manager log: http://thatsitradio.com/logs1/manager.html

Comment: Worker log: http://thatsitradio.com/logs1/worker.html

Comment: Please put this line to `repository/conf/log4j.properties` of worker node and restart the server. That will print debug logs in the error case.  `log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security=DEBUG`

Comment: worker log with debug: http://thatsitradio.com/logs1/workerd.html. manager log with debug: http://thatsitradio.com/logs1/managerd.html. In manager log, I see "Putting resource object in cache with key: /t/0000s7.com/ofer1/1.0.0/1.0.0/* and then "Found Authentication Scheme: None". In worker I do not see that, and APIKeyValidator complains that "Resource not found in cache for key" and then "Could not find API object in cache for key". My understanding is that APIKeyValidator is expected to receive this information from the manager, not sure why this is failing.

Comment: One more note: I left   <APIKeyValidator><ServerURL> on the default value https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}${carbon.context}services. Hope this is ok.

Comment: Since the Keymanager components are in manager node, you have to change "<APIKeyValidator>" of the worker to point to manager node.

Comment: Trying it I get
[https://10.1.0.7:9443/services/APIKeyValidationService] {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender}
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <10.1.0.7> != </localhost>

Is there a way to bypass the name check?

Comment: Posted an answer as it can be helpful to someone else too.

Comment: Have you changed the admin password?

Comment: Not yet. Still admin:admin.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Keymanager components are in manager node, you have to change `<APIKeyValidator>` of the worker to point to manager node.

If you have `-Dorg.wso2.ignoreHostnameVerification=true \` in `wso2server.sh` file, that should ignore the hostname validation.

Comment: I have -Dorg.opensaml.httpclient.https.disableHostnameVerification=true and -Dorg.wso2.ignoreHostnameVerification=true  in both server and client, but it insists on the error.

Comment: That's strange. I just quickly tried myself and it worked. Anyway, if that doesn't work you'll have to create and import certs properly.