# WSO2: API cannot authenticate in independent gateway

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, gateway

We are having similar problem as reported in [WSO2 Authentication failure on gateway node running WSO2 AM 2.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48644486/wso2-authentication-failure-on-gateway-node-running-wso2-am-2-1-0), but our configuration is slightly different, and we have done some additional test

Environment:
Ubuntu LTS 16.04.4
Java "1.8.0_171" (known reported issues, see below)
WSO2 2.1.0
We have deactivated the compression in the 3 nodes, editing the catalina-server.xml
Additional: We have repeated the tests after downgrading Java to 1.8.0_144. Same results.

We have deployed, in the same machine, 3 nodes
- 1 manager wso2server.sh start
- 2 gateways wso2server.sh -Dprofile=gateway-manager start
- Unique H2 databases set, shared for all nodes
(we are able to rebuild the environment in any moment, from scratch)

## Initial test

- We have configured API Key Validator using thrift. There is only one ThriftServer, started in the manager node
- Manager node key API Key Validator (changed real host name by example.com)

  ```
      <APIKeyValidator>
      <ServerURL>https://apimanager.example.com:9443/services/</ServerURL>
      <Username>${admin.username}</Username>
      <Password>${admin.password}</Password>
      <KeyValidatorClientType>ThriftClient</KeyValidatorClientType>
      <ThriftClientConnectionTimeOut>10000</ThriftClientConnectionTimeOut>
      <EnableThriftServer>true</EnableThriftServer>
      <ThriftServerHost>apimanager.example.com</ThriftServerHost>
      <ThriftClientPort>10397</ThriftClientPort>
      <KeyValidationHandlerClassName>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.handlers.DefaultKeyValidationHandler</KeyValidationHandlerClassName>
      </APIKeyValidator>
  ```
- Sandbox and gateway nodes key API Key Validator are the same configuration, except the parameter `<EnableThriftServer>` is `false`

*Test result*
In API Console, we get (we are using the PizzaShack API sample in GET /menu)

```
{ "fault": { "code": 900900, "message": "Unclassified Authentication Failure", "description": "Error while accessing backend services for API key validation" } }
```

*Gateway trace*

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-05-21 13:15:17,351]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.thrift.ThriftKeyValidatorClient} -  Login failed.. Authenticating again.. {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.thrift.ThriftKeyValidatorClient}
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-05-21 13:15:17,392]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler} -  API authentication failure due to Unclassified Authentication Failure {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler}
```

*Manager trace (API console)*

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-05-21 13:15:17,372]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2018-05-21 13:15:17,372+0200] from IP address  {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
```

## Test with debug enabled

Testing with debug is not possible due a previous bug (see comment of [Bee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/805563/bee) below)

## Additional tests

- Following the suggestions of the original post, we have changed the APIKeyValidator to WSClient. After some initial configuration problem, this work fine
- We have tried also calling with CURL, no change.

Comment: There was a bug when you enable debug logs. https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-5715

It's fixed in APIM 2.2.0. Actually, in 2.2.0 you don't need to enable debug logs to see the full error trace.

Comment: Thanks! Any clue about the other issues? I cannot use WSClient (due the JDK issue, even disabling compression? Or, any clue about why Thrift can be complaining?

Comment: Updated the post (we have reproduced the same error with JDK 1.8.0_144)

Answer (score 1):

This issue is related to the endpoint jwks url. You should go to the admin page > Key_namager then find the jwks url endpoint and chage it. This did help for my case!